# Преобразование чисел

Tags: python

Я пишу что-то вроде `list(str(000000))` и получаю `['0']`, как получить `['000000']`?
Единственное, что пришло в голову, это найти каждую цифру в числе (с помощью `%`) и добавить в строку, но можно же как-то сделать по-нормальному?
А еще: можно ли "реверсировать" число без преобразования (`123 -> 321`)?

Comment: Для  интерпретатора, что 000000, что 0000000000000 - все равно это 0.
Но % не поможет. Вы все равно не знаете, сколько именно нулей было введено.

Comment: У меня там все числа шестизначные. А с % я ступил, да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы точно знаете, что работать всегда будете с шестизначными числами, действительно можете воспользоваться "%". Пример:

```
a = 5050
s = "%06d" % a
```

После чего s == "005050".

Answer (score 0):

1.list(('000000',)) и все.

2.

```
s = 'abc'
s[::-1]
'cba'
```

Comment: 1. Дело в том, что 000000 храниться в переменной.

Comment: в строковой переменной или целой?

Comment: В целой, если бы была строковая - проблем бы не было.

Comment: эмммм, как в целочисленную переменную сохраняете 6ти значное значение начинающееся с нулей? секретом не поделитесь?
это математика уровня 5го класса примерно : все первые нули отсекаются.
смотрите вариант от Kozlov Sergei с форматированием текста, а от туда уже делайте реверс и преобразование в число..
имхо немного костыльно, но в целом пригодно